# CakePHP HABTM Save Single Header Record, linked against multiple existing children

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 2.9.1, have 2 tables in a HABTM relationship, I want to save the header record and save many associations in one go, but the child record is already existing, I seem to be able to save the data using a hardcoded list but not using a variable, I'm sure it's something silly I'm doing, I'm running inside a plugin, the model I want to link too is in the main code.

The child record must not be altered because it's handled by the main system, I'm just extending it's functionality by linking to it in our plugin.

```
// Header Record
class templatedoc extends TemplateModuleAppModel
{
    public $useTable = 'templatedocs';
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = [
        'Servicetemplate' => [
            'className' => 'Servicetemplate',
            'joinTable' => 'templatedocs_to_servicetemplates',
            'foreignKey' => 'templatedoc_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'servicetemplate_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'dependent' => false, // We don't want to delete the Service Template by mistake!
        ]

    ];

}
```

Here is my save, this works:

```
 $this->templatedoc->create ();
            $data = [
                'templatedoc' => [
                    'warning_adjust' => $prioritywarn,
                     'summary' => $summary,
                ],
                'Servicetemplate' => [
                    1,2,3,10    // Dynamic data needed here!
                ]
            ];

            $result = $this->templatedoc->SaveAll ($data);
```

But I can't have the "Servicetemplate" hardcoded, I've tried passing an array inside that array and removing it, imploding an array to make a comma separated list all I end up with is the header 'templatedoc' record being created but nothing in my link table

Only thing I can think is a difference is that the hardcoded list are int values, by data is coming from the database so will be an int inside a string, but I can't see that being an issue.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Sorry if it's something completely stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do in the end was store the items forcing an int, when associating in my foreach loop.

```
$items[] = (int) $id
```

Then this worked:

```
$this->templatedoc->create ();
        $data = [
            'templatedoc' => [
                'warning_adjust' => $prioritywarn,
                'summary' => $summary,
             ],
             'Servicetemplate' => [
                $items   // Dynamic data needed here!
             ]
        ];

       $result = $this->templatedoc->SaveAll ($data);
```

Seems very fussy it has to be type int, adding here in case someone else gets caught out, would love to know if there is a better solution.